# Unexpected Identifier Javascript SQL

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm trying to build a string of an sql statement using vars in javascript.

I got this line code

```
     var sql = "'INSERT INTO UPLOADS (poleID, submitDate, poleDamaged, poleDown, wireDown, brokenFixture, brokenBulb, fullname, phonenumber, email, comments, address, city, state, zipcode, lat, lng) VALUES (" + poleID + "," + submitdate + "," + poleDamaged + "," + poleDown + "," + wireDown + "," + brokenFixture + "," + brokenBulb + "," + fullname + "," phonenumber + "," + email + "," + comments + "," + address + "," + city + "," state + "," + zipcode + "," + lat + "," + "," + lng + ")" + "'";
```

and my Google Chrome dev tools console is throwing this error and pointing to the line above

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Any reason it is throwing this error?  All vars are valid.

Comment: Ignore the extra , in the statement.

Comment: @igor this is executing on their device to a sqlite database.  No connection to anyone else except for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. you missed + in two places and an extra comma...

```
 var sql = "'INSERT INTO UPLOADS (poleID, submitDate, poleDamaged, poleDown, wireDown, brokenFixture, brokenBulb, fullname, phonenumber, email, comments, address, city, state, zipcode, lat, lng) VALUES (" + poleID + "," + submitdate + "," + poleDamaged + "," + poleDown + "," + wireDown + "," + brokenFixture + "," + brokenBulb + "," + fullname + "," + phonenumber + "," + email + "," + comments + "," + address + "," + city + "," + state + "," + zipcode + "," + lat + "," + lng + ")" + "'";
```

Comment: You sir are correct.  Sorry for the stupid question.  I should've looked over it more.